# Migrating from MySQL to MongoDB - auto increment field

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, mongoid

Is there a way to guarantee a unique (auto-increment integer) field for MongoDB? I know you can do:

```
{ $inc : { field : value } }
```

But what if 2 queries hit at the same time? MySQL would insert one, then the other and both integers would be unique, but I don't actually know if Mongo does this or not.

Just to clarify, I know this isn't the ideal way to do it, but it's a temporary implementation until the data has finished migrating (user initiated) from MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$inc` is an [atomic modifier](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations), so yes, this will work. Make sure you use `findAndModify` so the find and modify are a single operation.

The problem is that `$inc` increments the value of a given document (row), which means you need to use a collection of counters, and apply the operation on that counter, then insert the actual document. I guess you know that, but felt it's worth to point it out to avoid confusion for readers who haven't read [the docs on auto-incrementing fields](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field).

Comment: Regarding FindAndModify; isn't this more expensive than just save? With findandmodify, it returns you back the entry, where as save simply does your update needed? Just curious..

Comment: That's true, but you will need the unique number that `findAndModify` returns. Id you'd read, then write your change, another thread that reads at the same time would use the same id. Likewise, when saving, the last one who writes would win. `findAndModify` makes sure that doesn't happen. Performance is better using an algo such as HiLo, because it needs much less db sync...

Comment: if you wanto achieve high performance, I recommend to guess how many ids you need and to "request" them to mongo in one operation

Comment: Upon testing this out today using data coming from multiple sources into a 'live' system, the findandmodify works an absolute treat. Thank you for all your help :)